# Linear Regression fitting

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I have first done a train/test split then fitted that data to a LinearRegression model shown below

```py
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size = 0.4, random_state = 101)

Log_m = LinearRegression()

Log_m.fit(X_train,y_train)

predictions = Log_m.predict(X_test)
```

I have been given another test data frame and wanted to fit that to the Log_m model which has been created. So I did

```py
predictions_t = Log_m.predict(fin_df1_t)
```

But I get the error message :

```sh
ValueError: shapes (1450,262) and (282,) not aligned: 262 (dim 1) != 282 (dim 0)
```

These are the shapes of dataframes

```
fin_df1_t (1450,262)

X_test (556,282)

X_train (834,282)

y_test (556,)

y_train (834,)
```

Comment: there are 282 columns in your training set  'X_train' .but the data frame 'fin_df1_t' only has 262 columns that's why it is showing an error regarding the shape.

Comment: you need to identify columns that are in used in X_train that are also in fin_df1_t  and subset that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature columns of new test data (262) are not equal to feature columns of Xtrain and Xtest (282), so it will always give an error. Both should have the same feature columns.
For example, Xtrain and Xtest have the same columns (282), so there is no error at that step.

Comment: So would I need to go into the data frames and make sure they both have the same amount of columns. Also, do those columns need to have the same labels ?

Comment: yes both should have same columns and same trend of labels.